# Align Text in a div next to an Image but vertically centered

Tags: html, css

```html
<div>
  <div style='display:inline'>
    <img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTkzNTY5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU4MzY1MTI@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,734,1000_AL_.jpg' height=300px>
  </div>

  <div style='display:inline'>
    Twin Peaks
  </div>

</div>
```

So I have the above image with a text next to it. The thing is that I want the text next to it to appear not on the bottom right but at the middle right/ top right of the image with some space between the image and text. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can use vertical-align: middle/top

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out after I posted the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div>
  <div style='display:inline'>
    <img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTkzNTY5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU4MzY1MTI@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,734,1000_AL_.jpg' style='vertical-align:middle' height=300px>
  </div>

  <div style='display:inline'>
    Twin Peaks
  </div>

</div>
```

Solved it by adding `vertial-align:middle` !

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute on the text and then align the text anywhere you want using the top property.

Example:

```html
<div>
  <div style='display:inline'>
    <img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTkzNTY5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU4MzY1MTI@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,734,1000_AL_.jpg' height=300px>
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline; position:absolute;">
    Twin Peaks
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using flex in the parent. Just set `align-items: center`

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <div>
    <img src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTkzNTY5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU4MzY1MTI@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,734,1000_AL_.jpg' height=300px>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
    Twin Peaks
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
 <div style="float: left;">
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTkzNTY5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU4MzY1MTI@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,734,1000_AL_.jpg" height="300px" />
 </div>

 <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
  Twin Peaks
 </div>
</div>
```

It'll set your Text top right side of your image.